# gluUnProject() is not recognised during build

Tags: android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, glu

I am trying to use `gluUnProject()` in my function to translate 2D coordinates of viewport to 3D world model. But, when I try to build, I get this message:

> D:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
>
> ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/tuxrider/src/course_load.o: in function get_OGL_position:jni/tuxrider/src/course_load.c:124: error: undefined reference to 'gluUnProject' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> /cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:397: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/libtuxrider.so' failed make: ***
>
> [obj/local/armeabi/libtuxrider.so] Error 1

Indexer in Eclipse, recognizes this function, but `ndk-build` doesn't. Is there a problem with OpenGLES 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gluUnProject()` is not a part of OpenGL ES. It is a part of GL Utility library `GLU` which is not exposed by the Android NDK.

There is a port of GLU library for Android - GLU ES: http://code.google.com/p/glues/ Just use it.

Answer (score 0):

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

This is a cryptic but common error from the linker (named ld), you have likely included the header for openGL-ES, but neglected to actually link against the library.

Comment: I don't understand. I didn't included header for GL, nor GLU, but all GL functions are working fine, except this GLU function.

Comment: It is possible that the eclipse indexer is looking at your local include directory, but your target system does not have the definition for gluUnProject() in the same location.  If you have not include the headers, then I'm surprised it built at all, it is possible that another header you included itself included part, but not all of GLU. IE everything you have been using except gluUnProject(), or the compiler died at that point and did not report the other symbols missing.